# How to Always Display Subreport in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2000

I have a sub report named AdmSubreport1 inside an access report 'Admissions'. The sub report pulls out data from a query AdmQuery. The subreport also has a report header. The problem is that when admquery returns no results, the subreport totally dis appears. Is it possible that even though admquery retuns no results, the subreport header would show atleast.

It is possible that i can put the heading outside of the subreport but i cannot consider this option as in reality i have four sub reports in the same report running 4 different queries (so i cannot fix the position of the heading on the report it has to move dynamically along with the sub report).

I tried looking for a setting that allow would allow me to do this but could not find one.

I use access 2003

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581035/access-display-textbox-control-in-sub-report-when-it-has-no-data

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something using VBA code for the form to show *something* when there is not data to show. Then the form will at least show, and show your header.

You can check out this link for a couple ideas: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-20.html.